# Output text between two PATTERNS if text matches a CRITERIA

Tags: linux, awk, sed, grep

I want to select blocks between PATTERN1 and PATTERN2 if text inside the block contains CRITERIA, otherwise discard the whole block.

**Sample task:**
Select text between PATTERN1='start' and PATTERN2='end', if some text between 'start' and 'end' matches CRITERIA='DCE', then output the whole block between 'start' and 'end'.

**Sample input:**

```
start
123
ABC
123
end
start
123
DCE
123
end
start
123
EFG
123
end
```

**Sample output:**

```
start
123
DCE
123
end
```

I've tried the following using awk, but couldn't find how to use CRITERIA between two patterns:

```
awk '/start/,/end/' input_file
```

Comment: if the accepted answer in the duplicate doesn't suit well, check out the other two awk answers..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

***EDIT:*** As per OP a Input_file may have match at the end too and may not have end string, so adding code as per that too now.

```
awk '
/start/{
  if(val)               {   print value   };
  flag=1;
  value=val=""}
/[dD[cC][eE]/ && flag   {   val=1         }
/end/                   {   flag=""       }
flag{
  value=value?value ORS $0:$0
}
END{
  if(val)               {   print value   }}
'  Input_file
```

***Explanation:***

```
awk '
/start/{                                     ##Looking for string start in a line if found then do following.
  if(val)               {   print value   }; ##Checking if variable val is NOT NULL, if yes then print variable of value.
  flag=1;                                    ##Setting variable named flag as 1 here.
  value=val=""}                              ##Nullifying variables value and val here.
/[dD[cC][eE]/ && flag   {   val=1         }  ##Searching string DCE/dce in a line and checking if variable flag is NOT NULL then set variable val as 1.
/end/                   {   flag=""       }  ##Searching string end in current line, if found then Nullifying flag here.
flag{                                        ##Checking if variable named flag is SET or NOT NULL here.
  value=value?value ORS $0:$0                ##Creating value whose value is current line value and concatenating in its own value.
}
END{                                         ##Starting END block of awk here.
  if(val)               {   print value   }} ##Checking if variable val is NOT NULL then print variable value here.
'  Input_file
```

---

Could you please try following `awk` and let me know if this helps you.

```
awk '/start/{if(val){print value};flag=1;value=val=""} /[dD[cC][eE]/ && flag{val=1} /end/{flag=""} {value=value?value ORS $0:$0}' Input_file
```

Adding a non-one liner form of solution too here.

```
awk '
/start/{
  if(val)            { print value  };
  flag=1;
  value=val=""}
/[dD[cC][eE]/ && flag{  val=1       }
/end/                {  flag=""     }
{
  value=value?value ORS $0:$0
}
'   Input_file
```

Comment: This works! But it doesn't examine the last block for some reason. If I add another criteria matching block at the end - it will not see it. Otherwise it works! :)

Comment: @Code_So1dier, do you mean that your Input_file may NOT end with `end`? if that is the case then we have to use `END` block in `awk` let me edit the code then, confirm  me once if I understood it correctly pleaee.

Comment: @Code_So1dier, please check my EDIT code now and let me know if that helps?

Comment: Yes! That fixes when matching block is last. But also found one more corner case - everything is printed after 'end' until either start of the new block, or end of file...

Comment: @Code_So1dier, ok got it and FIXED it in my EDIT now, kindly check once and let me know if All is Well with this one now?

Comment: @Code_So1dier, added explanation too here with my code.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation and time, I've picked up a lot of new knowledge!

Comment: How do you replace the criteria by a variable?

Comment: I got it: /'"$criteria"'/

Answer (score 2):

Since the start-end blocks are separated by empty rexords, you can use those for separating instead. Here with awk:

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{RS=""}/DCE/' file
start
123
DCE
123
end
```

**Edit**: Since the empty records were not there after all, let's separate with `end`s:

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{RS=ORS="end\n"}/DCE/' file
start
123
DCE
123
end
```

Comment: sorry, I separated sample input with empty lines only for visual aid :(. Actual input is not separated by a new line. I will edit it

Comment: Updated. See the edit.

Comment: Thanks for the elegant solution, it does what is needed. I've given correct answer to another guy because he was first and  I picked up a lot of new stuff, although it is much verbose solution.